# Joining in Mongo DB?

Tags: c#, sql, node.js, mongodb, nosql

For a hotel booking website, in SQL - let's assume I would have 2 tables

| Booking | BookingId | startdate | enddate | cost | HotelId(fk) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

| Hotel | HotelId | Name | Location | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

In SQL I would inner join Booking with Hotel to get all the details related to hotel as well.
In MongoDB, is there any way of doing this? Would it be the right approach to have 2 collections? Or should I just embed the hotel collection in booking collection? Please provide code for the best approach since I have only recently started dabbling in NoSQL DBs in general.

Comment: i would make them 2 separate collections because the number of bookings per hotel has the potential to grow unbounded. if it does you will be exceeding the 16mb bsondocument limit in mongo.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider what pieces of information you need from the Hotels collection when you query a Booking.

In SQL it is a common practice to normalize data, such as the hotel name, so that it is only stored once, then store a reference ID in related tables and use joins to retrieve that data, such as when looking up a booking.

In NoSQL a common practice is to partially de-normalize the data to minimize the number of queries.

For example, when you query bookings, do you really need all of the details for every booking and every hotel all at once?  Or do you just need enough information to be able to present a list/overview, and retrieve additional details only if the user clicks on the booking?

If you really do need all of the data right away, you need to choose between:

- store the _id of the hotel in the booking.  When you query use $lookup to retrieve the hotel data
- embedding all of the hotel data in the booking listing.  When any of the hotel data changes, also update all of the open bookings.

If partial data on the initial query is acceptable, store the _id, and minimal hotel details like name and location in the booking.  When querying for a list/overview of bookings, the hotel name and location are already present without the need for a join or separate query.

The remaining data for each hotel can then either be retrieved in the background while the user looks over the list, or retrieved on demand when the user selects a booking.

This hybrid approach would require updating all of the bookings when a hotel name or location changes (hopefully a rare event), while permitting faster retrieval of the data necessary for an initial display.  If the details are not requested for every booking every time, this would also reduce data transfer.

Which approach is best for a specific case will be very much dependent on the interface design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregation` with `lookup` in mongodb.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

```js
db.bookings.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: "hotels",
    localField: "HotelId",
    foreignField: "HotelId",
    as: "hotel"
  }
}])
```

This will give you `hotel` object nested inside the booking record.